# Blender with Huion pen and Windows ink

Tags: navigation

I have a Huion pen and I set up a button to middle click to rotate the view. It's working everywhere BUT Blender. There's nothing related to pen buttons in the preferences, is there an extra step to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in 3.0, it works whereas Wintab doesn't in 3.1

Comment: There are no developers here but it might be worth reporting it as a bug via the Help > Report a Bug menu. Please don't add extra information as an answer. You can edit your question and add extra information to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you already had a previous Blender version set up in the Huion program, the settings don't automatically transfer to the new version. To apply the settings to the new version of Blender, remove the existing Blender keybind set, and create a new one.